# Any way to use a designer for Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin

I heard good stuff about Xamarin and I liked the idea of designing a page once and using it on all platforms. But the thing that bummed me down is the fact that I have to design the pages with `C#`, which is a nightmare in my opinion.

I would like to see what I design (I am thinking Expression Blend). Is there any way to use a designer for `Xamarin.Forms` projects?

Comment: Have you tried using XAML for the design instead of raw C#? I don't *think* there's a designer view of that, but it would be clearer in markup than in C#, probably.

Comment: There is also some XAML intellisense in Xamarin IDE (like schema for XML) but none in Visual Studio right now. So I usually use Xamarin IDE for crafting XAML and Visual Studio for the rest.

Comment: Xamarin released Xamarin Forms previewer this year there are many resources this year about that how to use it, here is one https://blog.xamarin.com/live-xaml-previewing-with-the-xamarin-forms-previewer/

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Jon Skeet's comment..

Sadly in answer to your question the answer is No..

although they have just announced Xamarin Sketches which from my understanding is real time displaying of your code in their new android emulator. Whether it is going to be the same as a designer I don't know.
You can find more information [here](http://blog.xamarin.com/xamarin-platform-previews/)

Answer (score 0):

Based on my observation of Mono/Xamarin products in the past years, they should have a XAML designer in the near future (considering the facts that they already have iOS/Android designers). Xamarin.Forms is still a new concept, so I suggest you be patient and wait for a few weeks (or months).

But note that XAML is in most cases editable in plain text editor. I recently did a lot of Silverlight programming, but I don't even have Expression Blend installed.

Like others commented, what you should avoid is to use C#. That's too difficult to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

you could use the following IDE(paintcodeapp) to put your button and other staff and get generated code for Xamarin Forms.

http://www.paintcodeapp.com/

Answer (score 0):

At Xamarin Evolve 2014, I heard (both privately and in a session) that coming was a "preview" capability. Something that allows real-time previewing of Xamarin.Forms (assuming XAML). That was not described as a visual designer.